# how openstack get deleted server list by compute API or connection API

Tags: api, server, connection, openstack, openstack-nova

I want to get some delete server list like `openstack server list --delete` through the **[API](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/proxies/compute.html)** [operation](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/connection.html), how can I achieve that, THX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track but apparently didn't follow through. If you check out https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=list-servers-detailed-detail#list-servers you'll find the `servers/detail` [section](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=list-servers-detailed-detail#list-servers-detailed) where you'll find more details about the options:

> deleted (Optional)
>
> Show deleted items only. In some circumstances deleted items will
> still be accessible via the backend database, however there is no
> contract on how long, so this parameter should be used with caution.
> 1, t, true, on, y and yes are treated as True (case-insensitive).
> Other than them are treated as False.
>
> This parameter is only valid when specified by administrators. If
> non-admin users specify this parameter, it is ignored.

Comment: THX, get it, I found that in `servers(details=True, all_projects=False, **query)`.

Answer (score 0):

an awesome place that you can find deleted or stopped instances information on openstack is mysql. for example run this query:

#### ubuntu

```
#mysql -e "use nova; select * from instances \G;"
```

#### centos

```
#mysql -uroot -p(password) -e "use nova; select * from instances \G;"
```

your output can suprise you.

see cinder database also. promise you will find some important data.